# add top and bottom content in edit page custom taxonomy woocommerce

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

On the categories edit page, you can see the box titled top content and bottom content. By adding content inside, you can categorize content at the top or bottom of the page.
I created a custom taxonomy within the WooCommerce Products section. But in the edit section of these custom taxonomies, those two boxes are not there.
How do I add it to the edit custom taxonomy page?